# Node level with Stanford dependency parser

Tags: syntax, computational-linguistics, nlp, parsing

I am trying to find a way to select the node(word) level using Stanford dependency parser. But, i haven't found any method that help to get the node level. I will be very grateful for your help

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you're looking for. Can you add some examples up there?

Comment: thank you, i have get the answer. We should use depth(Tree) method which is inside ExhaustiveDependencyParse class